# Docusing Custom Connect url to publish not support http

Tags: docusignapi

So far i finished Docusing integration with our DMS including webhook listener, when we config for Custom Connect, url to publish not supporting http://, in some articles mentioned it support htpp and https, in some article not mention http will support,
I have demo sandbox account in Docusing, from my account setting page, if i enter url to publish link for webhook listener and i click save button, it will not save, it show error like "url need https"
Screenshot -http://prntscr.com/v3n6en
Pls advise me what i did wrongly ?

Regards,
Aravind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't use HTTP with Connect

This [guide](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/connect-https-only) explains it

Quote from Q&A:

> DocuSign Connect is used to transmit sensitive data about your envelopes across the Internet. As part of DocuSign’s focus on security, we are upgrading all notifications to use HTTPS only.

Hope this answer your question

Comment: Yes , i also read lot of documentation , some one article mention can use http and some one article  cant , here the link - https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/ndse-admin-guide-custom-connect-configuration-htm

Comment: here the screenshot which mention http also support -- http://prntscr.com/v4d3ig
in Docusing developer account, in connect setting, only support https , Ss -http://prntscr.com/v4d5bk

Comment: I understand your point. Previously HTTP was allowed as an option for sandbox accounts. Because of security HTTPS is now the only option for both sandbox and production accounts as you already experienced. Unfortunately it takes time for the documentation to be updated but this should not stop you switching to HTTPS and continue your development. Please remember, the only option for production account is HTTPS so you will need to implement it regardless